# Integrating $f_{XY}(x,y) = \frac{2}{1-x}\boldsymbol{1}_{y\in(0, 1-x), x \in(0, 0.5)}$ over $x$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

I have the joint pdf $f_{XY}(x,y) =\frac{2}{1-x}\boldsymbol{1}_{y\in(0, 1-x), x \in(0, 0.5)}$. I want to obtain the marginal pdf for $Y$.

\begin{align}
    f_Y(y) = \int_0^{0.5} \frac{2}{1-x}\boldsymbol{1}_{y\in(0, 1-x), x \in(0, 0.5)}dx \\
\end{align}

How do I integrate this function with the indicator variable? Is it simply
$$
f_Y(y) = 
\begin{cases}
1.386 \ \ \text{if } y \in (0, 1-x), x \in(0, 0.5) \\
0 \ \ \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
This looks like a very odd marginal pdf to me. As a sanity check, I wanted to integrate this to ensure it comes out to be 1, but the upper limit of this integration would depend on $x$ within is $\in (0,0.5)$. How does this integration work? I feel like I did not obtain the correct $f_Y$ to begin with.

Comment: @JwJJJJ I'm a bit new to the editing system, but I thought I had edited the indicator conditions. Did you edit them back to the original one? Were we editing at the same time? (It looks like the current edit is by you)

Comment: @user5965026 I added the constant c in the joint distribution.

Comment: @user5965026 I can help edit your question if you need.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\mathbf 1_{x\in(0,1/2), y\in(0,1-x)} =\mathbf 1_{0< x< \min\{  1/2,1-y\},0<y<1}$, then,
$$f_{Y}(y)=\int_0^{ \min\{  1/2,1-y\}}\frac{2}{1-x}\,\mathrm{d}x\quad,0\lt y\lt 1$$

Hence,
$$f_{Y}(y)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
2\ln2&,0<y<1/2\\
-2\ln y&,1/2<y<1
\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: Is the joint distribution even a density function...

Comment: @Winston Maybe there are some errors in my proof, I'll cheek it. Thank you.

Comment: The working of your proof isn't wrong! I'm saying the original "joint distribution" doesn't integrate to 1 over its support.

Comment: The joint distribution is indeed not a density function....,normalizing by a constant is available.

Comment: Why is it not a valid pdf? Doesn't it integrate to 1 if we integrate x from 0 to 0.5 and y from 0 to 1-x?

Comment: Oh, sorry guys, I had a typo in the indicator variable conditions. It should be valid now.